# Defining an SSL Custom URL Scheme for an iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, woocommerce

I need a callback URL that meets WooCommerce's REST API authentication endpoint URL and iOS Custom URL Scheme. According to the documentation the callback URL for WooCommerce has to be in this format: https://app.com/callback-endpoint but the URL Scheme to return a user to an iOS app is written in this format: AppNameURL://. Doing so gives the Error: The callback_url needs to be over SSL.
WooCommerce will return 4 parameters key_id, user_id, consumer_key, consumer_secret and key_permissions.

Is there a way to write a callback URL to send the information to the app or do I need to write a PHP function to capture the data then redirect to the app returning the captured data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a custom URL scheme for this anymore. Use a [Universal Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html), and it will handle the use case you're describing. Universal Links have been available since iOS 9.